# This C# code that checks the index of each letter of a word in the alphabet, then outputs if the letters add up to 100, does not output at all

Tags: c#, arrays, char

The title gives most of the details. `button1_Click` is invoked when `button1` is pressed by the user. `outputBox` does not contain any text even if I put a word such as "surely" (which adds up to 100 based on the indexes of the characters) into `inputBox`.

This code also seems inefficient to me because of the looping. If there is a way to remove the char loop, please tell me what it is, as I'm a beginner to C#. There's probably some sort of `Regex` method that I don't know about.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        string[] s = inputBox.Text.Split('\n');
        int i = 0;
        foreach (string u in s)
        {
            foreach (char c in u.ToCharArray())
            {
                int index = Array.IndexOf(alphabet.ToCharArray(), c);
                i += index;
            }
            if (i == 100)
            {
                outputBox.Text += u;
                outputBox.Text += Environment.NewLine;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: For why it's not displaying result for the word which you enter, you need to debug and check if the code follows the logic and why it doesn't sum up to 100.

Comment: The index of arrays in c# is 0-based, so `Array.IndexOf(alphabet.ToCharArray(), 'a')` would return 0, and the letters of "surely" add up to 94 -- 6 less than 100, 1 less for each letter in "surely".

Comment: Thanks. I forgot about that. It fixed the problem, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have added this logic for you to learn another logic that might be faster in execution, try it and test it:

```
string inputText;
List<char> alphabet;
int i, foundIndex, lastNewLineIndex;

// List is an array holder with a lot of ease operations (check online for good practice)
alphabet = new List<char>("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".ToCharArray());

// sort characters and its required for Binary Search Algorithm
alphabet.Sort();

inputText = inputBox.Text.Trim();
i = 0;
lastNewLineIndex = 0;
for (int charIndex = 0; charIndex < inputText.Length; charIndex++)
{
    // New Line Char
    if (inputText[charIndex] == '\n')
    {
        lastNewLineIndex = charIndex + 1;
        // Skip below code and go to next loop index
        continue;
    }

    // Binary Search is a fast searching algorithm used in case of sorted data with speed O(log(n))
    foundIndex = alphabet.BinarySearch(inputText[charIndex]);

    // Skip in case of not found
    if (foundIndex < 0) continue;

    i += foundIndex;

    if (i >= 100)
    {
        int length;

        // Get the index of right \n starting from foundIndex 
        length = inputText.IndexOf('\n', foundIndex);

        // in case of text ending with no \n after foundIndex
        if (length < 0) length = inputText.Length - lastNewLineIndex;

        // Chars length between left \n and right \n
        else length = length - lastNewLineIndex;


        // Get the Text Between left \n and right \n and add \n at the end
        outputBox.Text += inputText.Substring(lastNewLineIndex, length) + Environment.NewLine;
        // Exit Loop
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Also ToCharArray is not needed as List<T> accepts IEnumerable<T> as constructor argument and string implements IEnumerable<char>.

Comment: Thanks for the notes :)